# How to multiply two sinusoids with the same frequencies but are out of phase without the use of complex numbers.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, trigonometry, signal-processing

So as a part of my extended essay I am looking into the importance of complex numbers in signal processing. I am in high school, but I cannot seem to figure out how to multiply two sinsoids together without the use of complex numbers. There has to be a way. Here is the two that I am trying to multiply,
$$3\cos\left(\omega t + \frac{\pi}{4}\right) \times 0.5 \cos \left(\omega t - \frac{3\pi}{8} \right)$$
Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the identity:
$$\cos A \cos B = \frac{1}{2}[\cos (A + B) + \cos (A - B)]$$

Comment: Hi I used that identity and got, 1.5cos(5pi/8)+1.5cos(2wt-pi/8). I am not sure what to do from here. I want in the end the new sinusoid to be represented in the form of Mcos(wt+theta).

Comment: 1.5cos(5pi/8) is a constant and evaluate to -0.5740....

Comment: How does this help? Even then how do I get rid of the 2wt?

Comment: So you will get your sinusoid in the form of $A + M\cos(2\omega t+\theta)$. The form of $M\cos(\omega t+\theta)$ cannot be attained, at least without the use of complex numbers.

Comment: alright thank you so much!  I did not know that. If you use complex numbers you can get the answer in the same frequency.